# jQuery: How to return when data conditionally is requested via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, getjson

I have a function calling another function to get data.  That data might be locally cached, or I may have to go get it.  Locally cached is easy.  But if I go get it, via $.getJSON, without locking the browser by turning async off, is there some way to still get that data back to the original function?

Ie, in the following code:

1) Since bar() no longer exists when parseData() returns, where is dataX going?

2) Without having yet another callback layer that both bar() and parseData() would call, and without locking the browser while the request is going on, how can I get dataX back from parseData() to foo()?

```
var foo = function () {

    $('body').text(bar());

};

var bar = function () {

    var parseData = function (dataX) {
        // do something to data
        return dataX;
    };

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('someKey')) {
        return localStorage.getItem('someKey');
    else {
        $.getJSON('http://somewhere.api.com?fubar=good', parseData);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return when making asynchronous calls. Instead just call foo as a callback:

```
var foo = function (text) {

    $('body').text(text);

};

var bar = function () {

    var parseData = function (dataX) {
        // do something to data
        foo(dataX.someText);
    };

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('someKey')) {
        foo(localStorage.getItem('someKey'));
    else {
        $.getJSON('http://somewhere.api.com?fubar=good', parseData);
    }

};
```

Comment: Can $.getJSON pass arguments to parseData, outside of the jQuery default arguments?  ie, pass a reference to the (in this case) <option> which triggered the event which called foo() in the first place?  (I can provide it the reference, just don't know how to get it to be included).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. parseData can access everything in its closure scope.

Comment: Ah, ok, that'll work then.  I'll just overload foo() then to be able to be both callee and caller.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a return from the `bar` function so calling it directly in the `text()` jQuery function won't set any text (since the return isn't text).

You can change the flow of your code to pass in the element you want to change the text of and have the `parseData` function actually call the `.text()` function for the element:

```
var foo = function () {

    //here we call the `bar` function and pass the element we want to change the text of as an argument
    bar('body');

};

var bar = function (element_str) {

    //here we use the argument we passed to create a jQuery object of the element to use later
    var $element = $(element_str);

    var parseData = function (dataX) {

        //instead of trying to return the value from the server, we just set the text of the element passed in
        $element.text(dataX);
    };

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('someKey')) {

        //here we manually call the `parseData` function to add the locally stored string to the DOM
        parseData(localStorage.getItem('someKey'));
    else {

        //here we pass the `parseData` function as the callback function for this AJAX call so it can set the text in the DOM when the AJAX function has come back successfully
        $.getJSON('http://somewhere.api.com?fubar=good', parseData);
    }

};
```

Comment: bar() did have a conditional return: `return localStorage.getItem('someKey');`  The .text() is just a quick example; I need to return dataX back to foo() for foo() to do other things with it, so I can't just pass the element.  (foo() is inside a private module constructor; doing it this way, every foo() would have to reimplement the functions that bar() would otherwise do).

Comment: @BrianFreud - Yes, but `$.getJSON`'s complete method(`parseData`) doesn't get ran until the request is complete, which is AFTER the function has already returned `undefined` inside of the `.text()` method.

Comment: Yes, so the question is, how can I either make bar() persist, or at least make foo() wait, until the getJSON request has completed?  Or is the only possible way to do that to set the getJSON request to sync?

Comment: If it isn't sync, it will never complete before the function it was called in returns. And, making it sync isn't a very good idea to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible due to the request being asynchronous unless the server you are requesting supports CORS, in which case you can make the request synchronous. I wouldn't suggest doing that due to the bad browser experience that may cause.

I suggest allowing `bar` to accept a callback that you can use to perform an action on complete.

Edit:

Try this:

```
var foo = function () {

    $('body').text(bar());

};

var bar = function () {

    var parseData = function (dataX) {
        // do something to data
        localStorage.setItem('someKey',dataX);
        foo();
    };

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('someKey')) {
        return localStorage.getItem('someKey');
    else {
        $.getJSON('http://somewhere.api.com?fubar=good', parseData);
        return "loading...";
    }

};
```

What happens when the browser doesn't support localStorage? or are you just not targeting those browsers.

Comment: I'd thought of that, but couldn't get it to work.  foo() is a global function, and bar() is a private function inside of a constructor.  The constructor sets an event, and when the event triggers, foo() is called as the event's callback.  foo() is passed a reference to bar() by the event.  (So the constructor calls an external function, and passes a reference so the external function can call the private function inside the constructor.)

Comment: Calling bar() from within parseData() didn't seem to work since afaik, there's now no way to access bar() - parseData() can return to bar(), but trying to call bar() comes up with the expected function not found.

Comment: Yes, I'm not targeting those.  This is a small part of a large GM script aimed only at HTML5/localStorage-compatible versions of Chrome, FF, and Opera.